# When is Jessica Jones season 1 set?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, jessica-jones-2015, jessica-jones

In S1E3 of *Jessica Jones*, Luke tallies up the superpowered characters he knows of. But in season 3 of *Agents of SHIELD*

> Inhumans all around the world are being exposed to Terrigen, and gaining powers.

This suggests that *Jessica Jones* is set earlier than that. When is S1 of *Jessica Jones* set?

Comment: I have heard that *Jessica Jones* is supposed to be set *before* *Avengers: Age of Ultron* but I haven't found anything definitive yet; stay tuned.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### It takes place sometime in 2015.

In the second episode, Jessica does a search for admission records for the night she escaped Kilgrave, on January 20, 2014, and mentions that the bus crash was "a year ago".

[image: when was the crash?]

[image: searching for evidence]

#### Other anecdotal evidence

- In ep2, we see snow on the ground, but people in NYC are generally wearing light coats, or none at all
- In ep2, we see a poster on the train for something on October 6th or 8th. (this could be an old/very early poster, but it's worth mentioning)
- In ep3, Luke mentions "you, me, the big green dude and his crew"
- In ep3, a radio caller mentions "ever since those guys quote 'saved the city,' people have been making up stories about more super folk out there."
- In ep3, Trish references the Battle of New York and the alien invasion as something that was unlikely to happen, but does not mention Sokovia.
- We know that Jessica Jones happens sometime after season one of *Daredevil*, as the warehouse where Matt fights Nobu in *Daredevil* is the same one later turned into a drug warehouse in *Jessica Jones*. The warehouse is shown to have suffered damage from the fire in *Daredevil*.
- When Jessica meets Claire Temple, Claire mentions knowing and having experience with helping Matt.

[image: Transmissions From The Edge - October 6/8th]

[image: let it snow]

[image: this place looks familiar]

Since the issue with Inhumans is not exactly a quiet one, and since there is no mention of Sokovia or the events of *Age of Ultron* or *Ant-Man*, **I'd estimate that the show takes place at the very tail end of the 2014-2015 Winter season** - prior to *Age of Ultron* and the Terrigen release.

Comment: I think she also mentioned in the first episode that her time with Kilgrave was "over a year ago". I'll need to rewatch and confirm.

Comment: I did think there was a reference to Sovokia (although not by name), but maybe I’m thinking of *Ant-Man*.